# Word ribbons on office add-ins (not VSTO)

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, ribbon, office-addins

Is that possible to create an office add-ins to make multiple ribbons for Word 2016 (and customizes UI) like is possible with VSTO complement ? How to generate an xml manifest for it?

I'm trying something like that, but it doesn't work...

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
 <CustomTab id="Tab1">
 <Label resid="LabTab1" />
  <Group id="Group1Id1">
    ....                    
  </Group>
 </CustomTab>
 <CustomTab id="Tab2">
 <Label resid="LabTab2" />
  <Group id="Group1Id2">
    ....                    
  </Group>
 </CustomTab>
 <CustomTab id="Tab3">
 <Label resid="LabTab3" />
  <Group id="Group1Id3">
    ....                    
  </Group>
 </CustomTab>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

Thx

Comment: Which Office application are we discussing? Please show an example of what you tried that's not working and explain HOW it's not working.

Comment: Ok, i have up the post.

Answer (score 0):

Office add-ins commands have limited number of ribbon controls you are able to use. The controls in a tab limited to [Button and Menu controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands#step-6-add-extensionpoint-elements). There are certain list of [supported platforms and clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands) as well. You may probably get quick idea on the possibilities by watching "Channel 9" [Add-in Commands in the Office Ribbon](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/2016/P551) presentation.

EDIT:

Per documentation on [CustomTab element](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/customtab): On custom tabs, the add-in can create up to 10 groups. Each group is limited to 6 controls, regardless of which tab it appears on. **Add-ins are limited to one custom tab**.

Comment: I'm trying to add multiple tab.

Comment: @BenjaminOarces I have modified my answer. Unfortunately you are not able to have multiple custom tabs.